# Filtering group of selected data by the latest dates for specific article

Tags: sql, sap-ase

I'm trying to get data from SQL database with `SELECT`:

[image]

```
SELECT DISTINCT T2D.NO_ARTIKLU,
                T2D.NAZEV_ARTIKLU,
                T2D.DATUM,
                T10.NO_PARTNERA
    FROM D3000S.DIA2ZZ0D T2D, D3000S.DIA1ZZ00 T10, D3000S.DIA2ZZ00 T20
    WHERE T10.NO_PARTNERA = T2D.NO_PARTNERA AND T2D.AKTIVITA > 0
```

The problem is ->
There are most of duplicates that I want to filter with SELECT
and I need to show only article with the latest datetime.

Thank you for the answers.

Comment: **Always use proper, explicit, *standard* `JOIN` syntax.**  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result, all as formatted text (not images.) And take a look at [mcve].

Comment: Jarlh Its Sybase SQL

Comment: I just need to help how to filter that records by the latest datetime in T2D.DATUM,
And Im so sorry but I can not share any data

Comment: Try to use [group by](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36272.1570/html/commands/X96182.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Please see below query .Rank can be used to eliminate the duplicate values.

```
  SELECT * FROM
  (
 SELECT DISTINCT T2D.NO_ARTIKLU,
            T2D.NAZEV_ARTIKLU,
            T2D.DATUM,
            T10.NO_PARTNERA,Row_Number() OVER(PARTITION BY Duplicatidentifier ORDER 
    By Datetimecolumn desc)
    AS Rank 
     FROM D3000S.DIA2ZZ0D T2D, D3000S.DIA1ZZ00 T10, D3000S.DIA2ZZ00 T20
    WHERE T10.NO_PARTNERA = T2D.NO_PARTNERA AND T2D.AKTIVITA > 0
   ) AS B WHERE Rank=1
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but that looks like not correct syntax:
SQL Error [156] [S1000]: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OVER'

Comment: @Swerph did you changed the column names.?

Comment: Yes of course, Looks like my SQL engine doesn't support this type of commands

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, echoing a previous comment, you should use ANSI join syntax. Reasons include increased clarity  and support for full outer joins. The topic is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins)

An obvious problem with your query, is that you do not join the third table to anything. Fixing this gives:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T2D.NO_ARTIKLU,
                T2D.NAZEV_ARTIKLU,
                T2D.DATUM,
                T10.NO_PARTNERA
    FROM D3000S.DIA2ZZ0D T2D
    INNER JOIN D3000S.DIA1ZZ00 T10 ON T10.NO_PARTNERA = T2D.NO_PARTNERA
    INNER JOIN D3000S.DIA2ZZ00 T20 ON T10.NO_PARTNERA = T20.NO_PARTNERA
    WHERE T2D.AKTIVITA > 0
```